# Make so code doesn't stop if a program it opened gets an error

Tags: python

If the "test.py" encounters an error, the timer stops working. How do I make so the code keeps running?

```
while True:
    os.system('test.py')
    time.sleep(80)
    print('Sucess')
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","test.exe"])
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","chrome.exe"])
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! Take a look at the documentation for `try`/`except` blocks. You can find it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) :)

Comment: Or just drop `os.system` since you're already using `subprocess`.